# Regarding raising exception in middle of for loop in Ocaml

Tags: exception, ocaml, computer-science

I'm having an array in ocaml.array of type float option array array
for example :- [|[|Some 2.3;None;None|];[|Some 1.2;Some 2.4;None|]|] 
I have to add elements of that array. If I encounter None then we have to raise error else I have to add elements and return it.
So I'm using for loop I'm not understanding how to raise exception in middle of loop and exit loop

Entire code should be in Ocaml

Answer (score 1):

Well, we're not going to write your code for you :-). But the expression:

```
raise exn
```

will work anywhere (including in a for loop) to raise the given exception.

Here's an example using List.iter that looks for the first odd number:

```
let find_odd list =
    let exception Found_it of int in
    let look k = if k mod 2 = 1 then raise (Found_it k) in
    try List.iter look list; None
    with Found_it n -> Some n
```